# Как с помощью django-filter в django rest framework создать фильтрацию по объектам (записям) где поле time до-после сейчас?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

Класс `Filter` уже подключен к `view`. В модели есть поле `time` с `datetime` типом.
Чтобы например по запросу `127.0.0.1/api/objects?current=true`
получать объекты где дата-время в `time` больше текущей на сервере, а `127.0.0.1/api/objects?current=false` соответственно меньше. Что то по подобной логике.

Сейчас класс фильтра фильтрует только по заданному диапазону

```py
class ObjectsFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    time = filters.DateTimeFromToRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = ObjectsModel
        fields = (
            'time',
        )
```

Comment: так вам надо в сделать поле `current = filters.Booleanfilter(method=get_current)`, затем описать метод `get_current`, в котором вы будете возвращать тот или иной кверисет в зависимости от значения `current`.

Comment: @Dmitry Спасибо!